# Nagios CHECK_NRPE Could not complete SSL handshake

Tags: nrpe

I checked all over, there are many answers to this issue, but none worked.
I am following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-16-04

The Nagios host is ubuntu 16.04, the client is ubuntu 18.04
Nagios® Core™ 4.3.4

The Nagios server and web is running ok, I can see the localhost status us 'up' in the dashboard.

Something very weird: I installed NRPE 3.2.1 on both the host and the client, but for some reason on the host is 2.15

Host:

```
root@nagios-1:/tmp/nrpe-nrpe-3.2.1# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 10.142.0.50
NRPE v2.15
```

Client:

```
$  /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1
NRPE v3.2.1
```

Just to make sure, when running check_nrpe from client to server I am using '-2' option to force v2 packets, but I am still getting to error

I added the client ip to the nrpe.cnf (on server), and to be sure also the server ip to the client nrpe.cfg file.

I enabled debug to see the messages in the syslog. this is the response:

```
Dec  4 00:35:47 nagios-1 check_nrpe: Remote 10.142.0.50 accepted a Version 2 Packet
Dec  4 00:35:51 nagios-1 nrpe[9953]: Connection from 10.142.0.11 port 49889
Dec  4 00:35:51 nagios-1 nrpe[9953]: Host address is in allowed_hosts
Dec  4 00:35:51 nagios-1 nrpe[9953]: Handling the connection...
Dec  4 00:35:51 nagios-1 nrpe[9953]: Error: Could not complete SSL handshake. 1
Dec  4 00:35:51 nagios-1 nrpe[9953]: Connection from  closed.
```

On the host, port 5666 is open and listening

```
# netstat -at | grep nrpe
tcp        0      0 *:nrpe                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:nrpe               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

I compiled nrpe with --
I am not using xinetd. I use the daemon

```
# ps aux | grep nrpe
nagios    9866  0.0  0.1  23960  2680 ?        Ss   00:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d
```

Host nrpe conf file:

```
# grep -o '^[^#]*'  /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
log_facility=daemon
pid_file=/var/run/nagios/nrpe.pid
server_port=5666
nrpe_user=nagios
nrpe_group=nagios
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1, 10.142.0.50, 10.142.0.0/20,10.142.0.11
dont_blame_nrpe=1
allow_bash_command_substitution=0
debug=1
command_timeout=60
connection_timeout=300
command[check_users]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_users -w 5 -c 10
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
command[check_hda1]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/hda1
command[check_zombie_procs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s Z
command[check_total_procs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w 150 -c 200
include=/etc/nagios/nrpe_local.cfg
include_dir=/etc/nagios/nrpe.d/
```

If you need more info let me know and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!
I had two versions of NRPE on the host. The deamon was running 2.15. I had to kill this version, and I manually run the 3.2.1 version from its other location

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg -f
```

After that I was able to get a response in the client